# Implement interval analysis on top of PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, redis, intervals, aggregation

I have a couple of millions entries in a table which `start` and `end` timestamps. I want to implement an analysis tool which determines unique entries for a specific interval. Let's say between yesterday and 2 month before yesterday.

Depending on the interval the queries take between a couple of seconds and 30 minutes. How would I implement an analysis tool for a web front-end which would allow to quite quickly query this data, similar to Google Analytics.

I was thinking of moving the data into **Redis** and do something clever with interval and sorted sets etc. but I was wondering if there's something in **PostgreSQL** which would allow to execute aggregated queries, re-use old queries, so that for instance, after querying the first couple of days it does not start from scratch again when looking at different interval.

If not, what should I do? Export the data to something like **Apache Spark** or **Dynamo DB** and analysis in there to fill **Redis** for retrieving it quicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either will do.

Aggregation is a basic task they all can do, and your data is smll enough to fit into main memory. So you don't even need a database (but the aggregation functions of a database may still be better implemented than if you rewrite them; and SQL is quite convenient to use.

Jusr *do* it. Give it a try.

P.S. make sure to enable data indexing, and choose the right data types. Maybe check query plans, too.